# Vuex shared across packages in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, lerna

I am working in a monorepo that has a structure a little like,

```
- packages
  - web_app
  - mobile_app
  - white_labelled_product
  - shared_resources
```

I am wanting to integrate a vuex store into theses packages, now some of the store will be unique to the package, but alot of the vuex store will be used across all my packages so I was hoping I could create a new package and load in vuex modules where I need them,

```
- packages
  - web_app
  - mobile_app
  - white_labelled_product
  - shared_resources
  - vuex
    - dist
      - index.js
    - src
        - modules
          - users
            - state.js
            - actions.js
            - mutations.js
            - getters.js
            - index.js
            - types.js
```

In the above above example I have users modules and in the `index.js` file I would have something like,

```
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'
import getters from './getters'
import state from './state'

export default {
   actions,
   mutations,
   getters,
   state
}
```

Then to use it in another package I would need to do,

`import users from '@mypackages/vuex/src/modules/users/'`

Is there a way I can use the dist folder in my vuex package so I can just do,

`import users from '@mypackages/vuex'`

do I have to import it and then export it in the index.js in /dist?